# Animating CSS by transitions when a class is added to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the Foundation framework on a project & it's [Top Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html) feature for navigation allows for drop-down navigation to appear on hover.

During the *hover* event it adds a `.hover` class to the relevant element, therefore the changes in CSS pop into sight rather than animating by way of a smooth transition.

This got me thinking. **Is it possible to animate (via transitions or similar) the changes in CSS definitions?**

Take this example. Here is our default element:

```
<div class="a-box">Some content</div>
```

And it's default CSS:

```
.a-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

On hover the framework (which I do not wish to edit the core file to keep it clean for updates) adds the `hover` class. Making our element now look like this:

```
<div class="a-box hover">Some content</div>
```

Here could be some CSS for the hovered element:

```
.a-box.hover {
    width: 400px;

    // I thought perhaps adding the following would work but it doesn't appear to

    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}
```

I'd be keen to hear others POV on this! I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, but all the posts I've read relate to some form of jQuery animation.

Comment: Check out [Animate.css](https://daneden.me/animate/)

Comment: This is actually very similar to how AngularJS is trying to implement animations. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate -- there may be some additional insight there.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't far off the mark, [here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uvqBH/).

The main error in your example is that you have

```
<div class="my-box hover">Some content</div>
```

But your CSS is looking for `a-box` not `my-box`.

As a habit, I normally define the animation on the simplest (most general) selector for the element and then any additional selectors will benefit from it.

```
.my-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.my-box.hover {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Ah my mistake, that is a type-o. What I wrote above is an explanation of a concept rather than real code (I've edited the class names). The real issue seemed to be located in the fact I included my transitions within the `.a-box.hover` declaration opposed to original state.